# How to match all spaces in the string which starts with

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have HTML with some text and tags. For example,

```
Outer text with [some random text title="My Title Here"], and more text
```

I would like to return this html, but replace
1. `"` for **nothing**
2. all **spaces** for `&nbsp;`

**From the START of `title=` till `]`**.

So that result of above html will be

```
Outer text with [some random text title=My&nbsp;Title&nbsp;Here], and more text.
```

As I'm using PHP I'd like though to use `preg_replace` but no idea how to construct corectly search statement.

I've achieved something like this `(^title=(.+)])` but this only matches `title="My Title Here"]` - what I need is to subtract from it spaces and double quotes.

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself or are you looking for someone to do the homework for you?

Comment: use str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$string);

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar - That will replace all spaces in the string, while the question is about replacing just some spaces.

Comment: The best place to learn and test regex: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to accomplish this.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(title=)([^\]]+)/', function($match) {
    return $match[1] . str_replace(array('"', ' '), array('', '&nbsp;'), $match[2]);
}, 'Outer text with [some random text title="My Title Here"], and more text');
```

The regex

```
(title=)([^\]]+)
```

captures everything between `title` and a `]`. For a more detailed explanation see: https://regex101.com/r/cFOYEA/1

Demo: https://eval.in/703649

It also can be done without the capture groups, https://eval.in/703651 (assuming the starting anchor wont have a double quote or space in it).